# Core Bluetooth read descriptor value longer than MTU

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Is there a way to read all data in a **descriptor** when the value is longer than a single MTU?

I have a descriptor where the value is 56 bytes in length. I read the value using `CBPeripheral.readValue(for: CBDescriptor)`, but in the callback I only get what I assume is the first MTU's worth of data...

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
    if let data = descriptor.value as? Data,
       let newValue = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(newValue) // only first 22 characters!
        print(data.count) // 22, expecting 56!
    }
}
```

On the Android side I'm able to call `gatt.readDescriptor`, and get the full 56 bytes from `myDescriptor.getValue()` in `onDescriptorRead`.

I need a method that will allow me to read all 56 bytes without making the descriptor into a characteristic on the peripheral side. Is this possible with CoreBluetooth?

Comment: I think you should have the full value. But as Android read "all the bytes" and iOS skip the "low level" one, could that be the difference? It's been age since I've used CoreBluetooth, but I remember a time where Android had to construct ALL the part of the frames

Comment: This surprises me; my experience is that iOS will perform a "long read" procedure, which is almost certainly what Android is doing. I have not personally tried using the descriptor for the read. Have you tried with the characteristic instead? Does that one work, but the descriptor doesn't? Do you control this device (or do you have a good packet sniffer)? You can check the traffic and see if a long read is occurring. (I can't remember if the built-in macOS PacketLogger will work for this.)

Comment: Do see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241986/ble-read-long-characteristics-value-using-android-ios where @paulw11 suggests that iOS doesn't support this and you have to keep reading. That doesn't sound right to me (I'm not even quite clear how that would synchronize), and it doesn't match my experience. But he may have more insight.